# auto login using CURL for entering form data

Tags: curl

I want to enter a login form using curl. It seems that it use a function for encrypting data. The script I used for completing login form is as follows:

```
curl http://localhost.net/login? -F "username=uname;password=passw"
```

and this is the function

```
    function doLogin() {
    document.sendin.username.value = document.login.username.value;
    document.sendin.password.value = hexMD5('\220' + document.login.password.value + '\344\237\030\370\333\053\232\373\236\116\241\071\340\056\331\245');
    document.sendin.submit();
    return false;
    }
```

It seems that the password value is changing in each time login page loading. Any way to have an automated sign in to login page?

Comment: You should ask the page maintainer

Comment: what should i ask? I posted the question here so that not to ask page maintainer

Comment: "Ask how to login using curl?" or "what is this mysterious login process your site is using?". You can ask here, but I don't see how someone could help here

Comment: I posted its encoding function. the only thing I know is that it uses SISCO login page.